# Is there a way to get back Phpunit's staticExpects method?

Tags: php, phpunit

I know about decoupling, maintenability, etc so please dont come with "you musn't use static methods anyway". So, it is deprecated and removed now. Still, any chance to mock static methods? Is there? Or is any way to manually code back the `staticExpects()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Mockery, which is better then default PHPUnit mocking functionality

```
$mock = \Mockery::mock('overload:MyNamespace\MyClass');
```

[Mocking Public Static Methods](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/public_static_properties.html)